# Realm performance effect on my app when using executetransactionasync instead of executetransaction?

Tags: android, realm, android-thread

I am trying to insert an element whenever I receive a push notif in `FcmListener` class using `Realm` now I thought that as I cannot use `executetransactionasync` in this class because `this class does not have a looper`, that's why I thought using `executetransaction` in an Activity class where I am showing this newly inserted element, and from `FcmListener` I can call this method inside Activity class whenever I received the push notification.

Now I was just thinking as `executetransactionasync` method is async whereas `executetransaction` is synchronous.

**Will there be any impact on app performance or not** ??

Comment: are you asking if executing code asynchronous instead of synchronous affects the performance?

Comment: @TimCastelijns Yes, also especially for the case of `Realm`.

Comment: why? Performance is not usually the deciding factor when deciding between the 2

Comment: @TimCastelijns that's why I am asking can it be because one process is async and other is sync and because as we know when only one thread does the task it can cause delay or hang the app, that's why just a general thought that will async be better for my use case or not ??

Comment: If the thread has no looper, it's not the UI thread, so using synchronous transaction shouldn't cause any hiccups.